# Navigation between pages in Sencha MVC approach

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch. I am beginning with MVC pattern. I want to navigate from one page to another. In my controller i have wriiten a tap function. The alert box inside works when tapped but it is not moving to the next screen. I don't know where have i gone wrong. Please do help.
My app.js looks like this:

```
//<debug>
Ext.Loader.setPath({
'Ext': 'sdk/src'
});
//</debug>

Ext.application({
name: 'iPolis',

requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

views: ['Main','mainmenu','journalsearch'],

controllers: [
    'mainmenu'

],

icon: {
    57: 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
    72: 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
    114: 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
    144: 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
},

phoneStartupScreen: 'resources/loading/Homescreen.jpg',
tabletStartupScreen: 'resources/loading/Homescreen~ipad.jpg',

launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('iPolis.view.Main'));
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('iPolis.view.journalsearch'));
},

onUpdated: function() {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Application Update",
        "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
        function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    );
}
});
```

mainmenu.js:

```
Ext.define("iPolis.view.mainmenu", {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
requires: ['Ext.TitleBar','Ext.form.FieldSet'],
id:'menuPanel',
config: {
    fullscreen:true,





    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'iPolis',
            items: [
                {
                    //text:'Back',
                    ui:'back',
                    icon: 'home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    iconMask: true,
                    handler: function() {
                        iPolis.Viewport.setActiveItem('menuPanel', {type:'slide', direction:'right'});
                    }
                }]
        },

        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Menu',
            items: [



                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: '<div class="journal">Journal</div>',
                    labelWidth: '100%',
                    name: '',
                    id:'journal',
                    handler: function() {
                       // iPolis.Viewport.setActiveItem('journalPanel', {type:'slide', direction:'left'});
                    }

                }



            ]
        }







    ]
}



});
```

Journalsearch.js :

```
Ext.define("iPolis.view.journalsearch", {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
requires: ['iPolis.view.mainmenu','Ext.TitleBar','Ext.form.Panel','Ext.form.FieldSet','Ext.Button'],

id:'journalPanel',

config: {
  //  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    layout: {
       // type: 'card',
        animation: {
            type: 'flip'
        }
    },

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'iPolis',
            items: [
                {
                    //text:'Back',
                    ui:'back',
                    icon: 'home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    iconMask: true,
                    handler: function() {

                    }
                }]
        }
]
 }
});
```

the controller mainmenu.js:

Ext.define('iPolis.controller.mainmenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

```
requires: [''],

config: {
    control: {


        '#journal': {
            tap: 'onJournalTap'
        }


    }
},

init: function() {

},


onJournalTap: function() {


    alert('i am clicked');

   var a = Ext.getCmp('menuPanel');
  a.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('journalPanel'));

}



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function:

```
onJournalTap: function() {


    alert('i am clicked');

   var a = Ext.getCmp('menuPanel');
  a.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('journalPanel'));

}
```

Try using this command: console.log(a), and show what it logs, I will help you.

PS: basically that's what Ext.NavigationView is designed for. If you have many views and just want to set one ACTIVE view at one time, let's include them all in your container and later show them using setActiveItem(index of that view)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. On using this console.log(a), i get:  Ext.apply.create.Class.

Comment: In the editor, it shows a warning : Unresolved function setActiveItem()

Comment: It seems that you have another view called **Main** as well, please paste the source code of app/view/Main.js here, or it would be better that you send me a zipped file of your source code and I will help you debug it :)

Comment: I have removed that Main. I had used it as a container to display my mainmenu i.e menupanel. Now in my app.js i have: var view= Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('iPolis.view.mainmenu')); Now i can access view in controller. So i can use view.push(); But how do I pass another panel into push()??????? I actually extended 'Ext.navigation.View' instead of panel to make push work

Comment: Can u give me your mail id please. I will zip it and send.

Comment: using push method i have made some progress. Kindly look into it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. According to the source code, do you really need Ext.navigation.View for your application? Or did you just try to make a work-around? If you just want to make navigation between components work, I will refactor it.

Comment: I have used that to make it work. It is working fine except the home button function. Please check the new project i have sent you.

Comment: It seems that you want to go back after clicking Home button?
Please note that Ext.navigation.View works this way: everytime you want to navigate to a new view, use `push(new view)`, and if you want to go back, use `pop()`

Comment: If I am 10 screens ahead and want to back to the home screen should i pop 10 times? In each and every screen i will have home button so everytime how do i calculate how many pops has to be done?

Comment: basically that's what Ext.NavigationView is designed for. If you have many views and just want to set one ACTIVE view at one time, let's include them all in your container and later show them using `setActiveItem(index of that view)`

Comment: I had tried setActiveItem in the question i have posted. But was getting a warning :Unresolved function setActiveItem() If you could resolve and send my zip file back it will be very useful for me. I have one more query regarding the buttons in sencha. I have posted the query. Can you please respond to that question also please.

Comment: please paste the link to your new question here.
by the way, you should try using your old way (create items and use `setActiveItem`), if that bug still exists, please resend me the source code :)